# Installation does not exist after user has logged with Facebook

Tags: parse-platform

We have encountered this scenario with Parse.com FaceBook login. Here are the steps:

1. Download and install app from AppStore
2. User logs in using Facebook account

Normally, there is a new row in the _Installation collection, and also one in the _User collection. However, from time to time, the _Installation entry is missing while the _User entry for the user exists.

Our app requires a logical link between a user and his/her device in order to implement the one device per user policy.

The app breaks when the user (represented by the _User entry) cannot link because the corresponding _Installation entry is not there. We have only observed this bug on iOS 7.

Would you please check if this is actually a bug in Parse SDK? If so, when would a fix be available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't run into the exact problem you're describing, but I've encountered a few similar instances using Parse and Swift where the `_User` will be created and the `_Installation` object will be created, but they won't be linked. What I've done is add a function in the `ViewDidLoad` function of the `ViewController` of the main page of my app (first screen after the login screen) to make sure that both are set and linked. Hope that helps!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    if ((PFUser.currentUser()) != nil) {
            var current: PFInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
            current["userId"] = PFUser.currentUser()
            current.saveEventually()
    }
}
```

EDIT: In my project I've needed to add that code above because the following wasn't always saving the `_User` object to the `_Installation` object in my `AppDelegate` file the first time someone signed up for my app

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData!) {
    let currentInstallation:PFInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    currentInstallation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    if ((PFUser.currentUser()) != nil) {
        currentInstallation["userId"] = PFUser.currentUser()
    }
    currentInstallation.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean the _Installation data entry sometimes cannot get created until the code segment above finishes? Do you have an official bug report on such a misbehavior?
Thanks. BTW, the linking part is a feature specific to our app.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify the `_Installation` object is created in my `AppDelegate` file, but the pointer to the `_User` object isn't always saved in my `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` function so I needed to add the function in `viewDidLoad` to do the same thing to ensure they were linked. I don't have an official bug report on this behavior unfortunately